# GSON fromJson with complex JSONObject not working

Tags: android, json, gson

I'm trying to use GSON fromJson() with a simple JSONObject, but it's not working for some reason. And it's not printing any stacktrace at all. Maybe i'm doing something really wrong in my code and someone can help:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

json.put("id", "1");
json.put("name", "Test 1");

JSONObject json2 = new JSONObject();

json2.put("id", "2");
json2.put("name", "Test 2");

JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
array.put(json);
array.put(json2);

JSONObject jsonAll = new JSONObject();
jsonAll.put("tests", array );

Gson gson = new Gson();

Test[] data = gson.fromJson(jsonAll.toString(), Test[].class);
```

And my Test class:

```
public class Test {

    public String id;

    public String name;

    public Test(String id, String name){
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

I'm trying to parse this in Android, and it's not working or printing errors..

Solved:

Test[] data = gson.fromJson(**jsonAll.get("tests").toString()**, Test[].class);

Or use K Neeraj Lal answer, it's working too!

Comment: After couple of hours, the problem is that i need to do this:
Test[] data = gson.fromJson(jsonAll.get("tests").toString(), Test[].class);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you have to do. Create two classes `Tests.java` and `Test.java`.

**Tests.java**

```
public class Tests {
    List<Test> tests;

    public List<Test> getTests() {
        return tests;
    }

    public void setTests(List<Test> tests) {
        this.tests = tests;
    }
}
```

**Test.java** (Your Test class)

```
public class Test {

    public String id;

    public String name;

    public Test(String id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Now use `Gson` to parse the data as follows,

```
    Tests data = new Gson().fromJson(jsonAll.toString(), Tests.class);
    Log.e("Parsed Data", data.getTests().toString());
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem might be in the: 
`Test[] data = gson.fromJson(jsonAll.toString(), Test[].class);` line,

I changed it to 
`Test[] data = gson.fromJson(jsonAll.get("tests").toString(), Test[].class);` and it worked for me

The parser didn't know to look in the "tests" tag for the array